# Consider the system S which can take n input parameters and each parameter can take on m values

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, computer-science

(a) What is the maximum number of pairs a single test case for this system can cover?

"I know that there are m^n different combinations in this example, but i'm unsure how many pairs a single test case could cover."

(b) In the best case, how many test cases can provide full pairwise coverage?

(c) Calculate the total number of pairs the test suite must cover.

(d) Suppose that n = 13 and m = 3. What is the minimum number of test cases to be selected to achieve pairwise coverage?

"I know there are 1594323 (3^13) different combinations, but i'm not srue the min of test cases".

Comment: Perhaps I'm alone in this regard, but I don't understand what "pairs" you are referring to.  Also, what do you mean by "test cases" and the "test suite"?

Comment: if a function takes m different values (say f(x,y)) and x and y can each hold n different values, how many different "test cases" would it take to cover all the different possible combinations of x and y. here is a definition i've come up with in the research i've done:




""""""""An all-combination testing means considering all the k^n different test vectors. On the other hand, pairwise testing means that each possible combination of values for every pair of input variables is covered by at least one test case""""""""""

Comment: For (a), then, wouldn't the answer always be $\binom{n}{2}$?  As there are $n$ variables in a test case, there are $\binom{n}{2}$ pairs of variables that are covered.  However, if this is the case, why would the question ask for the *maximum* number of pairs a single case can cover, when they all cover the same number?